# How to customize the default message of display tag library x items found, displaying 1 to 4...

Tags: java, jsp, displaytag

I am using `Display Tag` library for some pagination and sorting. So far it is working perfectly fine but I need to change the default message `x items found, displaying 1 to 4..` to the screenshot below. I have changed some of the table properties already based on what I need but the one in the screenshot seems a little odd. How can I achieve this in display tag.

[image]

code:

```
<display:table id="data" name="intgList" requestURI="/integration/viewIntegration" class="fieldLabelCell" pagesize="4">
    <!-- Setting table properties -->
    <display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true" />
    <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="bottom" />
    <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.no_items_found" value=""></display:setProperty>
    <display:setProperty name="basic.msg.empty_list_row" value=""></display:setProperty>
    <!-- Displaying columns data -->
    <display:column property="lob" title="Line of<br>Business" sortable="true" class="displayColumns" />
    <display:column property="insuredName" title="Insured" sortable="true"  class="displayColumns"/>
    <display:column property="custPhone" title="Customer<br>Phone" sortable="true"  class="displayColumns" />
    <display:column property="policyNumber" title="Policy #" sortable="true" class="displayColumns" />
    <display:column property="createdDate" title="E-Sign<br>Created Date" sortable="true" class="displayColumns" />
    <display:column property="custEmail" title="Customer<br>Email" sortable="true" class="displayColumns" />
    <display:column property="esignNumDocs" title="# of E-Sign Documents" sortable="true" class="displayColumns"  />
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Here is the solution. The only thing is to add the images instead of hard coded less than and greater than signs. Basically I had to override the table properties. Below is the complete code snippet.

```
<display:table id="data" name="intgList" requestURI="/integration/viewIntegration" class="fieldLabelCell" pagesize="2" sort="list">
        <!-- Setting table properties -->
        <display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true" />
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="top" />
        <display:setProperty name="basic.msg.empty_list_row" value=""></display:setProperty>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.group_size" value="2"></display:setProperty>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.no_items_found" value=""></display:setProperty>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.page.separator" value=" of "></display:setProperty>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.first" value='<span class="pagelinks"> |< << | Page {0}<a href="{3}"> | >> </a><a href="{4}">>|</a></span>'></display:setProperty>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.last" value='<span class="pagelinks"> <a href="{1}">|< </a> <a href="{2}"> << | Page </a> {0} | >> >| </span>'></display:setProperty>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.full" value='<span class="pagelinks"> <a href="{1}">|< </a> <a href="{2}"><<</a> {0}<a href="{3}"> | >> </a><a href="{4}">>| </a></span>'></display:setProperty>
        <!-- Displaying columns data -->
        <display:column property="lob" title="Line of<br>Business" sortable="true" class="displayColumns" />
        <display:column property="insuredName" title="Insured" sortable="true"  class="displayColumns"/>
        <display:column property="custPhone" title="Customer<br>Phone" sortable="true"  class="displayColumns" />
        <display:column property="policyNumber" title="Policy #" sortable="true" class="displayColumns" />
        <display:column property="createdDate" title="E-Sign<br>Created Date" sortable="true" class="displayColumns" />
        <display:column property="custEmail" title="Customer<br>Email" sortable="true" class="displayColumns" />
        <display:column property="esignNumDocs" title="# of E-Sign Documents" class="displayColumns"  />
    </display:table>
```

Comment: This is working for me, but how can I add the img for the icons.